# Burninating the conspiracy theories tag

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklisting

I always disliked the conspiracy theories tag. First of all, it's a meta-tag but secondly, it's pejorative and slanted. As Neil deGrasse Tyson put it so well [on Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/neiltyson/status/56010861382336513),

> Conspiracy theorists are those who claim coverups whenever insufficient data exists to support what they're sure is true.

I remove it when I see it, but at least five questions are still tagged with it and it's likely that it's a tag we'll see reused in the future.

Jeff, could you just blacklist it, please?

Comment: Related: ["Conspiracy" not allowed in comments?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1922)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed on all counts -- it is removed.

(not blacklisting it let unless it comes back to life like a zombie..)

Comment: It did ;) though I am not sure if there's a reason to remove it

Comment: @jeff: It did came back and I've made it a synonym of `untagged`. Same goes for myth and urban-legend...

Comment: @skl I don't really support this; you've created a honeypot since the tags *exist* (as synonyms) they are inviting users to use them and then getting beaned with "untagged" is very close to editoralizing. This is not something I am comfortable with; you should open this as a meta topic for discussion.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy to simply undo that. It was suggested in TL and I thought it was the correct handling... Sorry about that.

Comment: @skl I am open to blacklisting the tags if they are recurring problems.

Comment: @jef both conspiracy-theories and urban-legends keep on coming back. Could you blacklist them, please?

Comment: @skl this is now done

Comment: @JeffAtwood Could you please remove/blacklist the [conspiracy] tag? It keeps on coming back (http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conspiracy)

Comment: @Sklivvz ok, I added `^conspiracy` to the tag blacklist, so any tag beginning with conspiracy is no longer allowed.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Ta, RegExes ftw.

Comment: So why do questions remain with this tag?

Comment: @ripper I just removed all conspiracy tags, I guess some predated the blacklist addition