# Is cryptozoology a pejorative tag that should be replaced with zoology?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is the [cryptozoology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptozoology) tag a pejorative tag, along the lines of the burninated [conspiracy theories](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/486/burninating-the-conspiracy-theories-tag)?

Does "cryptozoology" basically say "the people studying this are cranks who should be ignored"?

**Background:** I came across [How likely is it that the Ivory Billed Woodpecker is not extinct?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/how-likely-is-it-that-the-ivory-billed-woodpecker-is-not-extinct) today, and wondered about its tagging as [zoology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoology). The woodpecker is like the [Tasmanian tiger](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1851/the-extinction-of-the-thylacine-could-some-still-survive), a species known to have existed but whose current existance is disputed, but the question about the latter species is tagged [cryptozoology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptozoology).

Comment: Wikipedia lists it as a pseudoscience, so I would tend to agree that we should replace it with zoology. Though I'd like to wait for some more opinions on that before merging it.

Comment: Since the Skeptics is in its infancy and number of questions are less, I feel the number of tags should not be too large. So at this stage it is safe to rename it as zoology..

Comment: Those comments should be answers. @AIB @Fabian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's fine if applied correctly: it means looking for new "hidden" or controversial species and the term is used non-pejoratively in these cases (e.g. by Boing Boing). Some of these species have been found, so I would say it's a legitimate field of work.

Comment: I agree: Ivory Billed Woodpecker = Tasmanian Tiger = zoology. Loch Ness Monster/Big Foot = Cryptozoology. Out of interest, what such species have been found?

Comment: @odd First animal that comes to mind is the [Coelacanth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelacanth): "The coelacanths [...] were believed to have been extinct since the end of the Cretaceous period [...] the first Latimeria specimen was found off the east coast of South Africa, off the Chalumna River (now Tyalomnqa) in 1938"

Comment: oh if you mean "thought to be extinct, found alive", I understand. Its discovery was an exciting event, but not as startling as discovering a "thought to be a myth, found alive" sasquatch or dragon. I would use the zoology tag for the former and the cryptozoology tag for the latter.

Comment: On a technical point, would cryptozoology encompass [cryptomycota](http://arstechnica.com/science/news/2011/05/a-new-branch-found-in-the-fungal-tree-of-life.ars)?

Comment: @Oddthinking: Check out http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/has-there-ever-been-a-cryptid-proven-to-actually-exist