# "Conspiracy" not allowed in comments?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I just wanted to comment "Conspiracy over cock-up, always" on an answer, and got a popup "Contents can't contain that content".

I spent a long time trying to obfuscate the 'cock', only to discover that it was the other 'co..' word that was a no-no.

I can't quite believe this isn't a transient bug on my computer. The same comment works ok here on meta.

What's going on?

Comment: Coming in 10 years too late to remind people that comments should be used to improve clarity of questions and answers only.

Comment: Does that apply to yours? :D

Answer (score 5):

The word "conspiracy" is blacklisted when it is at the beginning of a post or tag. I suspect that this was a mistake made when the [conspiracy-theories](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conspiracy-theories) tag was blacklisted (see https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/525/5). The blacklist is universal, so it'll trigger also on posts and comments, not only on tags as it should.

We'll talk to someone from SE to adjust the blacklist.

Comment: Wait … we have a word blacklist? Uh … needless to say, I think this is a very bad idea.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That one is meant for stuff like spam links. The conspiracy stuff should have been in the tag blacklist, not the universal one.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah it's mostly for tags and temporarily used for spam URLs. I'm not sure it's ever (intentionally) been used to block words inside posts

Comment: conspiracy - Fixed! *Tags* that start with 'conspiracy' are still blacklisted, but nothing else.

Comment: @Shog9 shame on you using your developer tricks to cover up this conspiracy